# how to use ls instead of find?

Tags: linux, find, ls, wildcards

I was using `find` to loop over some files ,the targets are the files that have this kind of structure:

```
EDI_2016-03-03_09-45-09_TARGET-TYPE_4830_453a2cbb-b8d4-4982_6549_6116_xazfzeg.PDF
```

the goal is to find the files that starts with `EDI_` and contains `TARGET-TYPE` in the middle, using find the command was :

```
find . -name "EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*"
```

And since i'm going to use the output with a loop i don't want to use `find` and use `ls` instead(i've had a lot of problem with files with spaces and find).

This works : `ls EDI_`

- does not work: `ls EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*`
- and this does not work: `ls "EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*"`
- and this does not work: `ls 'EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*'`

and I dont really know why, if anyone can translate the `find` command to me that would be great .

Comment: Find parametrs are in double quotes. Should work for ls as well if you enclosed in double quotes there

Comment: `ls: cannot access "EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*": No such file or directory` is the error i get

Comment: And the same error is for fully unquoted ls?

Comment: yes , you can try make a `touch` of the file and then test by your self

Comment: can you use the ` to make it more clear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67284/discussion-between-kingofkech-and-gnudiff).

Comment: Are the target files located in one single directory or different subdirectories?

Comment: they are in `./Folder/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ touch EDI_2016-03-03_0945-09_TARGET-TYPE_4830_453a2cbb.pdf
$ touch EDI_2016-03-03_0945-09_TARGET-TYPE_4830hhh_453a2cbb.pdf
$ ls EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*
EDI_2016-03-03_09-45-09_TARGET-TYPE_4830_453a2cbb.pdf
EDI_2016-03-03_09-45-09_TARGET-TYPE_4830hhh_453a2cbb.pdf
```

Works for me. Bash shell Ubuntu recent LTS.

Answer (score 4):

What I would do :

```
for file in EDI_*_TARGET-TYPE*; do
    do_something "$file"
done
```